# WP_Query search for whole words

Tags: wp-query

I'm searching for science related terms.  Here's what I need my query to do.  If someone searches 'bio', they should not get results for terms 'biology' but they should for 'bio science'.  I need the query to return results for the whole word.  Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
    $queryArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'faculty',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 
            'key' => 'proposed_keywords', // name of custom field
            'value' => $keyword, // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
 );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna need regular expressions to accomplish that.

First of all, you need to change `'LIKE'` to `'RLIKE'` (or `'REGEXP'`).

Second, replace `$keyword` in `'value'` with a regex that involves word boundaries.

Like so:

```
  $queryArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'faculty',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 
            'key' => 'proposed_keywords', // name of custom field
            'value' => "[[:<:]]$keyword[[:>:]]", // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
            'compare' => 'RLIKE'
        )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The above 500's on me (wp-engine) so instead I used:

```
'value' => '[[:<:]]'.$keyword.'[[:>:]]',
'compare' => 'REGEXP'
```

Which works fine :-)